# how to fix "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2087, 4174]"

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, gridsearchcv, k-fold

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
kf =KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)
print(type(kf))

features = ['f0','f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9']

fold_idx=1
accrs= []
for train_idx, test_idx in kf.split(final_data):
    print('[Fold{}] train size={}, test size={}'.format(fold_idx, len(train_idx), len(test_idx)))
    train_d, test_d =final_data.iloc[train_idx], final_data.iloc[test_idx]

    train_y = train_d['class']
    train_x = train_d[features]

    test_y = test_d['class']
    test_y = test_d[features]

    model= RandomForestClassifier()
    model.fit(train_x,train_y)

    mean_accr = model.score(test_x, test_y)

    fold_idx +=1
    accrs.append(mean_accr)

print(np.average(accrs))
```

problem is here

```
23     mean_accr = model.score(test_x, test_y)
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2087, 4174]
```

and final_data is (20876,11)
I have already tried to reshape, but it doesn't work

I don't know why act like this
because when I only use RandomForestClassifier, it works well

and I have similarity problem with GridSerchCV what the ,,
in that case also

```
gcv.fit(train_x, train_y)
```

it had problem they say ValueError: Invalid parameter classifier for estimator RandomForestClassifier

Comment: and I can't sure that where is the destination to reshape

Comment: There's a typo inside your `for` loop in which you assign `test_y` twice rather than making new `test_x`

Comment: @Chris hahahaaa I'm dummy.  thank you for checking my codes it works!! Could I ask one more question?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you make another question since the comment section isn't meant for follow-ups :P

Comment: Okay, thank you I'll do that following your recommendation.